# why the component doesn't load in nested routing (react)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, nested-routes

Here i want to load the ShowIt component as a nested route but it doesn't work i mean when i click on the link i go to route of that but the ShowIt component (hello world) doesn't load and i really need to solve this problem

please help me

```
    import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';

const ShowIt = <div>Hello world</div>;

const Links = (
  <div>
    <Link to="news/components">Go to Components</Link>
    <br/>
    <Link to="news/states-vs-props">Go to states vs props</Link>
  </div>
);

const News = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        Links
      }
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="news/:id">
            <ShowIt />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
};

export default News;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `<Link>` outside a `<Router>`. So do this:

```
<Router>
  {Links}
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/news/:id">
      <ShowIt />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

There are few more issues in your code:

1. Make `ShowIt` a react component:

```
const ShowIt = () => <div>Hello world</div>;
```

2. Use a `/some-route` instead of `some-route`:

```
<Link to="/news/components">Go to Components</Link>
```

And, to access `id` in `ShowIt` component:

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
// ...
const { id } = useParams<{ id: string }>();
```